# Array Patch antenna

Tags: antenna

Array patch antennas are supposed to have high gain  and all the patches are supposed to resonate at the same frequency right (at least in those videos I have watched so far), So here is the thing, I want to design a array patch antenna with four resonating frequencies where each patch resonates at a specific (one of the four) frequencies. Is it possible to do so. I mean I tried a bit and no matter what I do, there is only one resonating frequency even when all the patch have different kinds of slot and dimensions. So what should I keep in mind, what should I aim for. Kindly guide me. Thanks.

Comment: You can't simply wire the antennas together if you want this functionality.

Comment: And note that you can make an array antenna out of elements other than a patch.  Notches and folded notches are two.  Even a slotted waveguide can be considered an array.

Comment: Thanks. I could get a basic idea for this concept now.

Answer (score 3):

> Array patch antennas are supposed to have high gain

If that was the design goal, yes. That's not generally the case - you build array antennas to get the characteristics you *want*, and that's not necessarily high-gain.

> all the patches are supposed to resonate at the same frequency right

Let's say they are all the same patch, or else I'd probably not call it an "array" antenna.

> want to design a array patch antenna with four resonating frequencies where each patch resonates at a specific (one of the four) frequencies.

That's a Multiband Antenna, not an Array Antenna.

> Is it possible to do so

Yes. Multiband antennas consisting of one discrete element per intended band do exist, but you will need to implement some frequency separation in the feedline, a *diplexer*. Obviously, otherwise, the non-resonant antenna elements will reflect energy back into the feed, which affects overall behavior.

Note that this is not an usual way of designing a Multiband Antenna, at least using patches, since that suggests that the bands of interest are close together to be covered either by a broadband design, or by a "complete" multiband design, where you don't design the individual elements to be only "active" for one frequency at a time but consider the whole multi-element antenna a joint optimization problem over multiple frequency ranges.

> (at least in those videos I have watched so far)

To be completely honest "videos I watched" sounds alarms for me: you can't really learn the basics of antenna design, let alone array antenna design, on video platforms, with videos that do not form a logical lecture. There's a solid amount of math to be understood, and methodology that you will need to understand sequentially. The fact that you're building an array antenna without considering the matching at different frequencies suggests you've been skipping quite a bit of the theory of antennas and hope to piece together an understanding from isolated videos. That is going to be very very hard!

Take the easy way: learn your basics from a lecture series on antennas, then learn about advanced antenna systems in another lecture series. There's a reason why such courses are taught over the course of a full academic year: they're hard! Trying to learn this from videos you find on individual topics makes it much much harder.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing out. I will learn the basic antenna theory first.

Comment: Erm... Did Balanis join StackExchange to answer this question?